# Spring Kafka - Batch processing related

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I have a batch listener (@transactional specified) and receives 100 messages. When processing these messages, I might fail to process only 10 of the 100 messages. Is there a way to selectively NOT acknowledge those messages so that only those 10 will be delivered again. Right now, because I have defined @transactional, it is all or none I think. If there is any exception, I am stopping receiving messages using kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop(); and everything gets delivered when I restart listener.

Also, second part of the question is, when do I do kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start() after I stop. without restarting the listener.